# C++ Basic Class Error

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile a simple program with a custom class. The issue is that I can't make a method called "union". I'm not using std or any library in the code so nothing should be polluting. What am I doing wrong?

**test_maximal_clique.cpp**

```
#include "BronKerbosch.h"
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

**BronKerbosch.h**

```
#ifndef BRON_KERBOSCH_H
#define BRON_KERBOSCH_H

class VertexSet
{
    public:
        VertexSet union(int a);
};

#endif /* BRON_KERBOSCH_H */
```

**BronKerbosch.cpp**

```
#include "BronKerbosch.h"
int VertexSet::union(int a)
{
    return a;
}
```

**Compile + Error:**

```
gcc -o bin/BronKerbosch.o src/BronKerbosch.cpp -c -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
In file included from src/BronKerbosch.cpp:1:0:
src/BronKerbosch.h:13:12: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
   int union(int a);
            ^
src/BronKerbosch.h:13:13: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘int’
   int union(int a);
             ^
src/BronKerbosch.h:13:13: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘int’
src/BronKerbosch.cpp:7:16: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘union’
 int VertexSet::union(int a)
                ^
make: *** [bin/BronKerbosch.o] Error 1
```

I change `union` to `unionn` and it compiles. Why? Is union a C++ reserved keyword?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword

Comment: ... literally a google search for your question would have given you the result: [is union a c++ reserved keyword?](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=is%20union%20a%20c%2B%2B%20reserved%20keyword)

Comment: Oh my god, I can't believe it. I was obviously being sarcastic when I asked that question.

Comment: You went through all of the effort to post this question just to be sarcastic? I don't get it. You missed April 1st by more than 2 weeks.

Comment: I've never seen the keyword "union" used in C++ before. I've been thinking all this time that some library was causing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a reserved word: [union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type#C.2FC.2B.2B) - this is why the compiler is complaining, but doesn't care once you change the name.